# Bubble Notification Wordpress - Hide if 0 / Show if +1

Tags: php, css, wordpress, notifications

I’m new in php & css.

After reading a lot and learning very little, I managed to program the notifications in my project in php and css. It works fine, shows the amounts (friends, messages and notifications) and redirects where it should.

My problem is that I need to “hide” the bubble of “0” when the user has no notifications and only show when if they have 1 or more notifications

[image]

**Functions.php**

```
if ( !is_user_logged_in()) {
    return $menu;
}

$user_id = bp_loggedin_user_id();
$user_url = bp_loggedin_user_domain();

$friends_url = $user_url . bp_get_friends_slug() . '/';
$msg_url = $user_url . bp_get_messages_slug() . '/';
$notify_url = $user_url . bp_get_notifications_slug() . '/';

ob_start();

<li><a><a href="<?php echo bp_loggedin_user_domain();?>friends"><span class="notifications_icons"><i class="fas fa-user-friends" style="font-size:17px;"></i></span><span class="my_bubble_notify"><?php echo friends_get_friend_count_for_user( $user_id );?></span></a></a></li>

<li><a><a href="<?php echo bp_loggedin_user_domain();?>messages"><span class="notifications_icons"><i class="fas fa-envelope" style="font-size:17px;"></i></span><span class="my_bubble_notify"><?php echo bp_get_total_unread_messages_count( $user_id );?></span></a></a></li>

<li><a><a href="<?php echo bp_loggedin_user_domain();?>notifications"><span class="notifications_icons"><i class="fas fa-bell" style="font-size:17px;"></i></span><span class="my_bubble_notify"><?php echo bp_notifications_get_unread_notification_count( $user_id );?></span></a></a></li>
<?php
    $menu_items = ob_get_clean();

    $menu = $menu . $menu_items;
    return $menu;
}

add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'my_counter_nav_menu' );
?>
```

**CSS**

```
.notifications_icons {
color: #ffffff;
vertical-align: middle;
margin: -7px;
}

.my_bubble_notify {
color: #ffffff;
border-radius: 3px;
background-color: #f7823f;
vertical-align: 20%;
position: relative;
    font-size: small;
    padding: 0.1em 5px;
}
```

Buddypress 6.0.0

Wordpress 5.4.2

site: http://www.gamerstroop.com

If you need, you can use test account (acc:test – pw:test)

I dont know if I can paste my site link here. If I can’t please remove it or let me know, thank you so much for reading and helping me! <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe if you wrap your my_bubble_notify span in an if statement it should work.

So for eg.

```
 <li>
    <a>
       <a href="<?php echo bp_loggedin_user_domain();?>friends">
          <span class="notifications_icons">
            <i class="fas fa-user-friends" style="font-size:17px;"></i>
          </span>
         <?php if(friends_get_friend_count_for_user( $user_id ) >= 1) { ?>
           <span class="my_bubble_notify"><?php echo friends_get_friend_count_for_user( $user_id );?></span>
         <?php } ?>
       </a>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Solved! thank you so much @kandi_galaxy

If somebody need it functions:

`bp_friend_get_total_requests_count

bp_get_total_unread_messages_count

bp_notifications_get_unread_notification_count`